# Drop Item If More Than 1 Item Present

Tags: python

I'm working on a piece of code, and it is for a little AI creature to randomly come into a room, and look to see if there is anything there. If there is anything that the player has touched before, then it takes the item. The next room it goes to it drops that item and may pick up a new one. So far, I have:

```
import random
rooms = ['kitchen', 'livingroom', 'basement']
itemsstatus = {'Umbrella': 1, 'Coin': 1}
itemsstatus['Umbrella'] = raw_input()
print "itemstatus['Umbrella']", itemsstatus['Umbrella']
roominventory = ['Umbrella', 'Coin']
goblininventory = ['baseball']
notpickedanythingelse = 'true'

gotoroom = random.choice(rooms)
if(gotoroom == 'kitchen') or (gotoroom == 'livingroom') or (gotoroom == 'basement'):
    ininventory = len(goblininventory)
    if(ininventory >= 1):
        roominventory.append(goblininventory[0])
        goblininventory.remove([0])
    else:
      print ""  

    for items in roominventory:
        if(itemsstatus[items] == 1) and (notpickedanythingelse == 'true'):
            goblininventory.append(items)
            roominventory.remove(items)
            notpickedanythingelse = 'false'
        else:
            print ""
    notpickedanythingelse = 'true'

    print roominventory
    print goblininventory
```

The itemstatus[''] = rawinput() will be done automatically by the game and won't be a raw imput, it is just here so I can test it. As well, each room will have it's own inventory and loop, but this is just for the simplicity of it. The goblin will pick up an item, and keep it, but it won't drop the one it already has (it can only carry 1 thing at a time). How can I get it so that it will drop the item it is holding once entering a new room?

Comment: Are you having a particular problem with your code?  Can you provide sample output and expected output?

Comment: It gives an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: That's because you can't remove something from a list if it's not in the list to begin with.

Comment: Expected output would be printed: `['Umbrella', 'baseball']` and then `['Coin']`

Comment: How can you fix it so that it can take the item out of the goblin's inventory and put it into the room's inventory?

Comment: `list.remove([0])` is saying remove `[0]` from the list, which likely isnt what your array contains.   You are just trying to pop off the front of a queue.  See Alexbclay below.

Answer (score 0):

`goblininventory.remove([0])` is incorrect.  You should use `goblininventory.pop()` to remove the first element from the list.

See here for more info on `remove` and `pop`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists